# 'Inversion' of option chain: calls are more expensive than puts above the strike price! GME

Tags: options, call-options, put-options

[image]Over the past two days there has been a weird phenomena on GameStop's options where the call options are more expensive than the put options above the strike price.  I would have imagined that some arbitrage strategy would eliminate those situations quickly.  What does it indicate when that doesn't happen?

I also notice that that the $1 call and $1 put are really close to each other.  Is that from the same effect?

Comment: Which columns are Bid, Ask, and Last? And which are you considering as the price?

Comment: It's LAST, CHG, BID, ASK, VOL, OPEN INT. and the three rows after the current price have the 'weirdness' that I'm talking about most noticeably.